# Automapper chaining forallmembers and forallothermembers

Tags: automapper

I am trying to ignore few members and put some condition on current members:

```
        CreateMap<UpdateProfileViewModel, UserSettingModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PhoneNumber, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PhoneNumber))
            .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null))
            .ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.Ignore());
```

ForAllMembers I cannot use since I already used ForAllMembers.

How can I ignore null values from source and at the same time ignore all other members for mapping?

Comment: Your code looks fine, what's the issue here?

Comment: You can’t chain

Answer (score 3):

So, because of `ForAllMembers` and `ForAllOtherMembers` returns `void` I suggest to use `opts.Condition()` method, although this solution is not so elegant

```
CreateMap<UpdateProfileViewModel, UserSettingModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opts => { opts.Condition(p => p.FirstName != null); opts.MapFrom(p => p.FirstName); })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opts => { opts.Condition(p => p.LastName != null); opts.MapFrom(p => p.LastName); })
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PhoneNumber, opts => { opts.Condition(p => p.PhoneNumber != null); opts.MapFrom(p => p.PhoneNumber); })
            .ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it is by storing the mapping configuration in a variable and then call the "ForAll" methods using the variable:

```
        var UpdateProfileViewModelToUserSettingModel = CreateMap<UpdateProfileViewModel, UserSettingModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PhoneNumber, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.PhoneNumber))
            .ForAllMembers(opts => opts.Condition((src, dest, srcMember) => srcMember != null));
        UpdateProfileViewModelToUserSettingModel.ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.Ignore());
        UpdateProfileViewModelToUserSettingModel.ForAllMembers(opts => // other logic);
```

I'm not sure if you are supposed to use both ".ForAll" methods at the same time and that is why they are null, but this has been working for me.